# Laravel resize and upload to storage

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to resize, rename and upload the image using laravel Storage, intervention on laravel5.
Here is my upload code:

```
if( $request->file('logo_image') ){
        $logo_path = $request->file('logo_image')->store('university/'.Auth::User()->id);
                   if ( $logo_path ){
                    Storage::delete($university->logo_image);
                }
                $university->logo_image = $logo_path;
}
        $university->update();
```

It is storing the image on folder like: **storage/app/public/university/1/fjkdhjkfdh.jpg**

Now I want to rename image name like university-name.jpg and also resize and upload to sam directory.
So I should have two images one is **storage/app/public/university/1/university-name.jpg.jpg** 
and other is **storage/app/public/university/1/thumbnail/university-name.jpg**

I play around with this for the whole day but no success.

```
if(Input::file())
    {

        $image = Input::file('image');
        $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $path = public_path('profilepics/' . $filename);


            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200)->save($path);
            $user->image = $filename;
            $user->save();
       }
```

Please someone can help me?
Thanks in advance.